# Why is the image NULL (javascript)?

Tags: javascript

so this is my code:

```
import menuiconexpand from './OBH-Logo-Font.png';
```

...

```
<img src={menuiconexpand} className="menuiconexpand" />
```

...

```
document.getElementById(menuiconexpand).style.display = "block";
```

My problem is, that visual studio says, that the object is NULL. Why is ist null?

Comment: What are you importing from a png graphic file?

Comment: So let me get this straight, you are importing from a png, not setting any id attribute, and wonder why the IDE sais `getElementById` returns `null`? Also i think you are missing a tag for react or something that does the interpolation there, otherwise you are missing quotes aswell.

Answer (score 0):

> This is because menuexpand doesn't have image or you are displaying it
>   incorrectly.

Your path must be incorrect while you are importing. Just right click on the image you are interested in image and click on copy path.use that path while importing. Now, replace all the back slashes to forward slash in the path.

Also change :-

`document.getElementById(menuiconexpand).style.display = "block";`
to

```
document.querySelector(".menuiconexpand").style.display = "block";
```